# Silent Authentication for OneDrive

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, onedrive

I am writing a program for a client and they are running into storage issuses on their server and as such have decided to go with Cloud storage. As the web application is in VB.NET they are electing to go with OneDrive.

Having had a look at their API it seems that OneDrive wants the user to sign in with their personal Microsoft Account and upload the files to their personal OneDrive. My client wishes for them to be uploading the files to their business OneDrive via a "silent authentication" done on the fly when the file picker is loaded.

The API doc's are not much help as far as this is concerned ([WL.init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh550844.aspx), [WL.login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh550845.aspx))

TL;DR How do you authenticate to a "business" OneDrive account and not the users using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like OneDrive for Business is a completely different one to the personal OneDrive system.  You have to use the SharePoint API's to access thiings: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2013/08/13/access-skydrive-pro-using-the-sharepoint-2013-apis.aspx

No filepicker by the looks of things, which was the one thing I needed!!

Comment: That's true. The APIs that Jeanine linked too are a little friendly and designed for OneDrive for Business specifically. I'll pass along the desire to have a file picker for web integrations.

Comment: @RGregg Thanks very much!  The file picker for OneDrive personal is really great, something as easy to use for OneDrive for business would be very useful!  Appreciate you passing it on.

Comment: I am having the same problem. My question is, can I use the same features as the OneDrive SDK? I need to let users upload (unnoticeably) powerpoint presentations and pick up the embed code to show on a website. The docs are so insufficient...

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive for Business has a preview REST API to do basic file/folder operations: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

With this, you can authenticate users with Azure AD and access their business data.